# How to compare two files byte per byte, but also account for missing bytes?

Tags: python

I have two files containing random bytes. An original, and one that was sent back and forth to a remote target.

I need to check if both files are identical. Let's take this table as an example:

| Byte # | File1 | File2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 01 |
| 2 | 05 | 05 |
| 4 | 08 | 08 |
| 5 | 0D | 0D |
| 6 | FF | 1A |
| 7 | AA | AA |

Byte 6 is not the same, so it should detect this. So far, not very difficult. Just loop over all bytes (or in my case: chunks) and check if they are the same.

However, I also need to be able to detect if a byte went missing!

| Byte # | File1 | File2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 01 |
| 2 | 05 | 08 |
| 4 | 08 | 0D |
| 5 | 0D | FF |
| 6 | FF | AA |
| 7 | AA | BC |

We now should NOT report bytes 2 to 7 incorrect, but only report byte 2 as missing. So our checking algorithm should record this "offset" and continue using it for all following bytes.
However, I can't really imagine how this would be done if 1) we read the files in chunks; 2) if there can be thousands of bytes missing in a row.

Also note that the files can be several GB's big. So the algorithm needs to be somewhat efficient.

I wonder if there's a good method for this? Google has let me down unfortunately.

Comment: Why don't you compare checksums?

Comment: Diff algorithms can handle this, though implementations are usually geared towards comparing text files. They report missing *lines*, but treat missing bytes within a line as a single diff. Conceptually, there's no difference for a binary file: think of it as a text file with one byte per line.

Comment: @mkrieger1 because we need to generate a BER (Bit Error Ratio). I need to know exactly what bytes are bad, and then compare the bits in each of the non-matching bytes.
Simply knowing the files are different is not sufficient.

Comment: @chepner I copy pasted the question wrote above to ChatGPT. It suggested me to try the Rabin Karp algorthim. I'm trying that one now, but from what I can read... I'm not sure if it will work without being able to load both files in its entirety in memory. (since they can be 10's of GBs large, this is not feasible). I also think that in my use case the window of the algorithm would have to be huge, because we can get several seconds of missing data, at Gigabit speeds.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance may be a better start than Rabin Karp.

Comment: @tevemadar I glanced over the wikipedia page. It's indeed more or less what I'm looking for. However... I can't imagine that doing that on 10's of gigabytes of data, potentially containing several megabytes of errors, will be possible in any reasonable time. (Note that my current method only takes a couple of seconds. Which is already longer than I would like).
Ideally I would have something similar to the Linux tool `diff`, but then on byte-level.
(Even though I doubt that such a thing exists).
Note that "what you ask can't be done" is also an acceptable answer for me.